# Prove, that positive orthant is an open subset of Rn

Tags: analysis

Show that the positive orthant $$R=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)~|~x_i>0, i=1,2,\ldots,n\}$$ is an open subset of $R^n$ by finding a formula for $е$ in terms of the $x_i$'s

Comment: What is $e{}{}$?

Comment: It is meant to be epsilon. Btw how do you turn symbols into a formula?

Comment: Google "StackExchange LaTeX guide". Someone needs to put a link at the top of Math SE webpage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that for every point $x$ in the orthant, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that the ball at $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ is contained in the orthant. Let $B(x,\epsilon)$ denote this ball.

Let $\epsilon=\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be the minimum coordinate of $x$, and observe that $\epsilon>0$. For any $y\in B(x,\epsilon)$ and any coordinate $y_i$ of $y$, we must have $|y_i-x_i|^2\leq \|y-x\|^2<\epsilon^2$, so $|y_i-x_i|<\epsilon$. Thus
$$
x_i-y_i\leq |y_i-x_i|<\epsilon,
$$
so $y_i>x_i-\epsilon\geq 0$. Hence all of the coordinates $y_i$ are positive, so $y$ is contained in the orthant. This proves that $B(x,\epsilon)$ is contained in the orthant, so it is an open set.